# How to directly save filtered images in a different directory in PHP?

Tags: php, directory

I applied a filter to the `.jpg` images of a folder as follows:
`$images = glob('images/*.jpg');
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $image_prefix = "image-beautiful-";
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            $rand = rand(50, 500);
            imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 75, 15, 10);
            $new_image = imagejpeg($image, $image_prefix .$rand.'.jpg');
            imagedestroy($image);
        }`

The generated images save in the main directory. How can I directly save them to another folder like `generated-images` using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the doco for [imagejpg](https://www.php.net/imagejpeg), the second parameter is the path and filename, so try adding the folder to the image prefix:

```
$image_prefix = "generated-images" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "image-beautiful-"
```